# Change Tracking Issue with Entity Framework Core in Console App

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, parent-child, change-tracking

I've been experimenting with Entity Framework Core 5.0 using .Net Core (3.1) Class Libraries and Console App. I've created 2 demo classes in one Class Library project, one class is a principal entity and the other a dependent entity. They are:

**Principal Entity**

```
public class MyList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MyListItem> MyListItems = new List<MyListItem>();
}
```

**Dependent Entity**

```
public class MyListItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyList MyList { get; set; }
    public int MyListId { get; set; }
}
```

Then in a Console App, I try to add some data to the Entities and persist into a SQL Server dB using EF 5.

**DbContext**

```
public class DemoContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyList> MyLists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MyListItem> MyListItems { get; set; }        
}
```

**Console**

```
private static DemoContext _context = new DemoContext();

private static void AddData()
{
        //Add List
        var list = new MyList();
        list.Name = "Primary List";
        list.MyListItems = new List<MyListItem>
        {
            new MyListItem { Name = "Seconday List 1" },
            new MyListItem { Name = "Seconday List 2" }
        };

        _context.MyLists.Add(list);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        
}
```

There is nothing special going on here, however, for some reason, only the principal (parent) entity is persisted to the dB, the dependent (child) entities are not.

Struggling to see why. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I have a feeling you aren't getting tracking, For now you can manually add MyListItems to the context, but chances are you just need to modify the MyListItem list to support tracking, you might just have to change the list to an ICollection

Comment: @johnny I’ll try your suggestion, thanks. I’ve based my code on an EF Core Pluralsight Course by Julie Lerman, and I believe she may have used List as opposed to ICollection, but I need to confirm this. I also haven’t set the DbContext to not track changes, so it’s a strange one.

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server? I've run into issues before when I use MySQL. Also, Lists implement ICollections, so you should stick with List since it includes ICollection functionality already. Really, you should be using DbSet<>, but still

Comment: @Chad Yes, using sql server.

Comment: Make sure your relationship is defined correctly. I just tried it on some of my EF Core code and I got an error, but I had my relationship wrong.  I use the Fluent API to define any non-standard relationship. To test to see if your relationship is correct, manually add data in SSMS, then query the data, using a `.Include`, then set a breakpoint and see if that variable has any data in the related entity

Comment: @tcode I don't see you're code first file, please provide a dump of the relations